# Show that the Diophantine equation only have trivial solution

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let the Diophantine equation be $x^2 + y^2 = cz^2$ for $c = 6 \mod 8$, show that this equations only have trivial solution $(0,0,0)$. I can show this for the case that $c = 6$ but for the general one, I tried using the fact that $cz^2 \in \{ 0,6 \} \mod 8$ but this leads nowhere. Any advice ?

Comment: What values can $x^2 \bmod 8$ take?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis $x^2 \mod 8$ can be $\{0,1,4\}$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis edited my answer

Comment: But since $x^2 + y^2 = 6 \text{ mod } 8$ has no solution, dont we only have to look at $x^2 + y^2 = 0 \text{ mod } 8$ which lead to $x \in \{ 0,2,4\} \text{ mod } 8$ ?

Comment: Yes, so you find that $z$ must be even, and then so must $x$ and $y$ be even. Now look at the original diophantine equation $x^2 + y^2 = 6z^2$, and think about what it means that the only non-trivial solutions (if any) necessarily have $x,y,z$ all even.